# Bash: ".profile" not loaded despite nonexistance of .bash_profile or .bash_login (Debian 10)

Tags: linux, bash, debian, profile

Reading the documentation in `~/.profile`, on my Debian system, it is stated that

```
  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.         
  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
  # exists.
  # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
  # the files are located in the bash-doc package.

  # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
  # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
  #umask 022
```

however the file `.profile` is not being loaded.

I know this because `flux` is not being loaded at startup, and it will not load if `$HOME/.local/bin` is not in the `PATH` variable, and this variable is set in `.profile`.

I assume it is a fairly trivial fix/explanation. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening or otherwise help me to debug the reason? My system is Debian 10 (testing).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `~/.profile` is only loaded *once*, directly after logging in. This is useful for setting the path, but not much else.

If you want something to be executed *every time* you open a shell, place it in `~/.bashrc` (or your shell equivalent).

If you want something executed when you start X (like `flux`), place it in `~/.xsession`.

Leave `.profile` alone, it will only give you headaches.